# Streaming remote audio file with AVPlayer throws some errors on macOS

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, avplayer

I'm trying to stream a remote audio file with `AVPlayer` on macOS. It plays the audio, but throws some errors. What do these errors mean and how do I eliminate them?

Here is my code.

```swift
var player: AVPlayer!

let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: URL(string: "MP3_URL_HERE")!)
player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
player.play()
```

The errors are:

```
startConfigurationWithCompletionHandler: Failed to get remote object proxy: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "connection to service named com.apple.rtcreportingd" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=connection to service named com.apple.rtcreportingd}

[BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C1.1:2][0x100b05890] get output frames failed, state 8196

TIC Read Status [1:0x0]: 1:57
```

P.S.

1. I checked `Outgoing Connections (Client)` in App Sandbox.
2. The audio URL is secure. (https://)
3. There is no UI related with the player. All this code is in `AppDelegate.swift`.